# Delete file function allow to delete only a specific file. How to adapt to a ListView with switch statement?

Tags: java, android, listview, switch-statement

I have a list view that display files stored in internal storage (files are display without their extension).

i have implement the `OnItemLongClickListener` with "switch" statement, to allow the user to delete a file of his choice from the list.

Unfortunately i was able just to add a function that can delete only a specific file.

I need a delete function that can delete the file pressed in the list. Because of the "switch method" that change position to the files on the list if one or more files are deleted, this make  my problem even worst!.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public void list(){

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/");
    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {

        String temp = filelist[i].getName();
       theNamesOfFiles[i] = temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf('.'));

    }
    Arrays.sort(theNamesOfFiles);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, theNamesOfFiles);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list();

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
                  @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

                      switch(position){

                      case 0:{

                      }
                      break;

                      case 1:{

                          }
                          break;

                      case 2:{    


                          }
                          break;

                      case 3:{



                          }
                          break;

                      case 4:{

                          }

                          break;
                      }
            return true;
        }
    });
}



public void doDeleteFile(int position){

    File fileToDelete = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/path/", "A.map");

    if(!fileToDelete.isDirectory()){

        try{
            if(fileToDelete.delete()){  

                System.out.println("File delete operation success");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("File delete operation failed");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception :"+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }else{

        System.out.println("It is  not a file");

    }

}

    }
```

Comment: let us see your code for the listview

Comment: hello. i ave posted the MainActivity. Thanks for your interest

Comment: here `Arrays.sort(theNamesOfFiles);` you are loosing the relation between a file and its name.

Comment: i need this to get the files in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

Going to need more details than this.

But it looks like you should be passing the name of the file to your delete function and using that to create the file reference. You say you're not displaying the file extension. If you know they're all the same extension, you can add it manually. If not, you're going to have search for it.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have add the whole file. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Write a Custom Array Adapter that works on `File` instead of `String` and trigger the delete method on the specific `File`-Object. Override `getView` method in the Adapter to show the filename without the extension. Use [this](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/) as an example how to write a Custom Adapter. The way you do it now, by Strings and espacially the line:

```
File fileToDelete = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/path/", "A.map")
```

is very error-prone. Work on the `File` objects instead. I'm confused about your switch-statement it doesn't make sense there. (Maybe try other things while learning to program?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am very new on android so is really hard for me (almost impossible) understand your explanation.. :(

Comment: try to understand the code in the link I gave you, maybe search for other tutorials that explain a custom adapter